# openssl ./config shared error (libcrypto.a)

Tags: openssl

```
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(x86_64-gcc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
libcrypto.a(x86_64-gcc.o): could not read symbols: Bad value'
```

I got this error while trying to compile and make openssl.

I have tried

```
export CFLAGS=-fPIC
```

But still no luck in solving the error.  Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

I also face same problem. so I solved it the following way:
First uninstall that file and download new version like openssl-1.0.2-latest.tar.gz

1. untar this file using command `tar -xf  openssl-1.0.2-latest.tar.gz`
2. `export CFLAGS=-fPIC`
3. `./config shared --prefix=/your/path`
4. `make`
5. `make install`

Comment: this works..........

Answer (score 2):

I got this error, after first doing `./config` without `shared`, then getting aware that I need shared libraries, and running

```
./config shared ...
make
```

The problem disappeared with `make clean` and then doing from the beginning

```
./config shared ...
make
make test
make install
```

Comment: make clean did the trick for me!!!!